# redux-form defaultValue does not work

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Here I have a `select` field with a `defaultValue`:

```
  <Field name="preference" component="select" defaultValue="tabs">
    <option />
    <option value="tabs">Tabs</option>
    <option value="spaces">Spaces</option>
  </Field>
```

This does not set a default value. Furthermore, I get the following error in my console:

> index.js:2178 Warning: Select elements must be either controlled or uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or the defaultValue prop, but not both). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled select element and remove one of these props.

According to [this page](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/field.md/), I can pass `Field` a `defaultValue`.

What am I missing here?